# One json param contains data in array or object. How to check data is array or object using GSON

Tags: android, gson

I have web service which can not be change. So I have one param called **content**. This param contains data either array or object. I mean sometime i got data in array format and sometime i got data in object format.

I am using gson library (https://github.com/google/gson) for parsing json. I have create a custom class and used that param here .

```
class {

@SerializedName("content")
    private List<Content> content;

  public List<Content> getContent() {
        return content;
    }

    public void setContent(List<Content> content) {
        this.content = content;
    }
```

so when i am getting data in array. it is ok. But it is crashing for object.

```
 com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was STRING at line 1 column 409 path $.response.content
```

**Updated:**

When param **content** is array then it is parsing correct. but when **content** param is in string. i am getting error.

```
 com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was STRING at line 1 column 410 path $.response.content
```

I used TypeAdapterFactory.

```
  public class ArrayAdapterFactory implements TypeAdapterFactory {

    @Override
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public <T> TypeAdapter<T> create(Gson gson, TypeToken<T> type) {

        if (type.getRawType()!= Templetegt4StoryResponse.Response.Content.class) return null;

        TypeAdapter<Templetegt4StoryResponse.Response.Content> defaultAdapter = (TypeAdapter<Templetegt4StoryResponse.Response.Content>) gson.getDelegateAdapter(this, type);

        TypeAdapter<T> typeAdapter = (TypeAdapter<T>) new AddressAdapter(defaultAdapter);
        return typeAdapter;

        //return (TypeAdapter<T>) new AddressAdapter(defaultAdapter);
    }

}


public class AddressAdapter extends TypeAdapter<Templetegt4StoryResponse.Response.Content> {

    protected TypeAdapter<Templetegt4StoryResponse.Response.Content> defaultAdapter;

    /**
     * @param defaultAdapter
     */
    public AddressAdapter(TypeAdapter<Templetegt4StoryResponse.Response.Content> defaultAdapter) {
        this.defaultAdapter = defaultAdapter;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    @Override
    public void write(JsonWriter out, Templetegt4StoryResponse.Response.Content value) throws IOException {
        defaultAdapter.write(out, value);
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    @Override
    public Templetegt4StoryResponse.Response.Content read(JsonReader in) throws IOException {
        System.out.println("in.peek = "+in.peek());

        if (in.peek()==JsonToken.STRING) {
            in.skipValue();
            return null;
        }
        System.out.println("in.peek = "+in.peek());

        return defaultAdapter.read(in);
   }
```

}

I am calling it

```
  Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().registerTypeAdapterFactory(new ArrayAdapterFactory()).create();
 return gson.fromJson(str, Templetegt4StoryResponse.class);


public class Templetegt4StoryResponse {

  @SerializedName("content")
    private List<Content> content;


  public class Content{

        @SerializedName("sequence_no")
        private String sequence_no;

        @SerializedName("is_url_code")
        private String is_url_code;
}
```

}

this is json. Content param can be in two format.

```
content: [
{
sequence_no: "1",
is_url_code: "is_url",
}
]


content: "this is new text",
```

Comment: Did you check my answer?

Comment: @Krish Thanks Krish. I updated my question. When param contains array then it is parsing correct. but when content param is in string. i am getting error. **com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was STRING at line 1 column 410 path $.response.content**  kinldy have a look

Comment: @Krish kindly check sir

Comment: Try this logic http://www.javacreed.com/gson-deserialiser-example/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In GSON you can use custom serializers,

Create a Custom TypeAdapter like this,

```
class ArrayAdapter<T> extends TypeAdapter<List<T>> {

    private Class<T> adapterclass;

    public ArrayAdapter(Class<T> adapterclass) {
        this.adapterclass = adapterclass;
    }

    @Override
    public List<T> read(JsonReader reader) throws IOException {

        List<T> list = new ArrayList<T>();
        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().registerTypeAdapterFactory(new ArrayAdapterFactory()).create();

        final JsonToken token = reader.peek();
        // Handling of Scenario 2( Check JavaDoc for the class) :
        if (token == JsonToken.STRING || token == JsonToken.NUMBER ||
                token == JsonToken.BOOLEAN) {
            T inning = (T) gson.fromJson(reader, adapterclass);
            list.add(inning);
        } else if (token == JsonToken.BEGIN_OBJECT) {
            // Handling of Scenario 1(Check JavaDoc for the class) :
            T inning = (T) gson.fromJson(reader, adapterclass);
            list.add(inning);
        } else if (token == JsonToken.BEGIN_ARRAY) {
            reader.beginArray();
            while (reader.hasNext()) {
                @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
                T inning = (T) gson.fromJson(reader, adapterclass);
                list.add(inning);
            }
            reader.endArray();
        }

        return list;
    }

    @Override
    public void write(JsonWriter writer, List<T> value) throws IOException {

    }


}
```

and create a factory for typeAdapter like this ,

```
public class ArrayAdapterFactory implements TypeAdapterFactory {

    @Override
    @SuppressWarnings({"unchecked", "rawtypes"})
    public <T> TypeAdapter<T> create(final Gson gson, final TypeToken<T> type) {

        TypeAdapter<T> typeAdapter = null;
        try {
            if (type.getRawType() == ArrayList.class) {

                typeAdapter = new ArrayAdapter((Class) ((ParameterizedType) type.getType()).getActualTypeArguments()[0]);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return typeAdapter;

    }

}
```

After this register this factory with your gson object,

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().registerTypeAdapterFactory(new ArrayAdapterFactory()).create();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (json instanceof JSONObject)
  //you have an object
else if (json instanceof JSONArray)
  //you have an array
```

Comment: yes. But i am using GSON library. and paring has been done in class. So i am not able to put logic here.